# [jQuery]Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, syntax-error

I have searched through all the similar topics here, but can't find information that leads the solving of my specific problem. I get a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token {.

By taking away sections of code at a time, I found the following function to cause the problem:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'render_edu_hook_javascript' );

function render_edu_hook_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";

    $("#edu_institute").focusOut(function () {
        var data = {
            'action': 'render_edu_hook',
            'institute': $('#edu_institute').val()
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, response){
            console.log(response);
            $( "#edu_programme" ).autocomplete({
                response
            });
        };
    });
    </script> <?php
};
```

Comment: can you please show us the rendered output, not your php code?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` inside function ?

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir OP uses PHP to render his JS code ...

Comment: And the reason is that this is the only way I found in Wordpress to use AJAX calls. Or, just because I'm really new to PHP, JS, jQuery and AJAX (so basically everything I need ^^).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jQuery.post` call does not seem that correct:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, response){
    console.log(response);
    $( "#edu_programme" ).autocomplete({
        response
    });
};
```

Shouldn't that be

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $( "#edu_programme" ).autocomplete({
        response
    });
});
```

Please see the documentation of [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for further information.

Btw, you can also use the newer API:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $( "#edu_programme" ).autocomplete({
        response
    });
});
```

Comment: @downvoter: care to elaborate so that I can fix my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, response){
```

This is wrong. I don't know what it should be, but it's wrong. Fix that.

Comment: See Andreas Niedermair and Norlihazmey Ghazali's answers for the fix

Answer (score 0):

Try change jquery post into this form, `response` is returned value from success callback i guess, then you should wrapped it inside function block :

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
   console.log(response);
   $( "#edu_programme" ).autocomplete({
       response
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't upvote yet, but you have earned one. Thank you.